Vertical tabview with jetpack compose android
I tried multiple options with ScrollableTabRow or TabRow it is now having any property to set the orientation to vertical.

Any other ways like colums with scrollabble?
Did not find any property to set the orientation
Row {
    ScrollableTabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
        contentColor = Color.White,
        edgePadding = 0.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
    ) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { tabIndex, tab ->
            Tab(
                selected = selectedTabIndex == tabIndex,
                onClick = { onTabClick(tabIndex) },
                text = { Text(text = tab) },
            )
        }
    }
}


A Row only has one orientation, horizontal. The vertical variant would be a Column (better suited here: LazyColumn).
However, this looks more like a fit for a ListDetailPaneScaffold. It consists of two panes, one displaying a list of selectable items and the other displaying details of the item that was selected. Also see the Material Design Guide to learn more about this from the design perspective.
You will need these gradle dependencies:
androidx.compose.material3.adaptive:adaptive-layout
androidx.compose.material3.adaptive:adaptive-navigation

Keep in mind that this is quite new and just graduated to beta. For more see the development page.
If you are looking for a means of top-level navigation then a NavigationRail would be better suited.
